# SQL absolute value sum and iterate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Lets say i have table with that looks something like this:

## cns_amt ---- cusip_nbr

-3000 -------------------- 00162Q205 
4000 -------------------- 00162Q205 
6000 -------------------- 00162Q205 
8000 -------------------- 00162Q205 
10000-------------------- 33733B100 
-2900 -------------------- 33733B100 
1000-------------------- 33733B100 
8000 -------------------- 33733B100 
7000-------------------- 464286178
-1200 -------------------- 464286178
1000-------------------- 464286178
1000 -------------------- 464286178

How can I make it so I get the results:

## total_amt ---- cusip_nbr

21000------------------------00162Q205 
21900-----------------------33733B100 
10200------------------------4642861

Basically I would like to sum each the absolute value for each distinct cusip_nbr and return a result that plots each cusip_nbr and its respective absolute value sum. (Only three distinct cusip_nbr 's are shown here but i have hundreds of them, each with a cns_amt that needs to be summed)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `ABS()` to get the absolute value, and `SUM()`:

```
SELECT cusip_nbr, SUM(ABS(cns_amt)) 'total_amt'
FROM Table
GROUP BY cusip_nbr
```

Demo:  [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/189b7/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

```
select cusip_nbr, sum(abs(cns_amt)) total_amt from table_name group by cusip_nbr
```