# SQL get count of value

Tags: sql, count

I have the following table. Now I want to count the amount of each value in this table.

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| -1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

-1 and 1 should be seen as 1, so the output should be

| value | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

Does someone know a quick fix?

Comment: `GROUP BY` the absolute value?

Comment: You can use SUM(ABS(column_name)). Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708406/sql-absolute-value-sum-and-iterate).

Comment: You can use `SUM(ABS(column_name))` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17708406/sql-absolute-value-sum-and-iterate)

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by value, and making such values the absolute value so you ignore the negative sign:

```sql
SELECT
ABS(VALUE) VALUE, COUNT() COUNT
FROM
table
GROUP BY 
ABS(VALUE)
```